# IRS ACA 1095B BulkRequestTransmitter: Invalid WS Security Header - SOAP UI

Tags: soap, irs

I am trying to Invoke IRS ACA 1095 B Ws through SOAP UI. I have configured Keystore in SOAP UI which when imported says OK. I have signed the 3 elements referring the IRS Doc, ACABusinessHeader, ACATransmitterManifestReqDtl and Timestamp. I have tried with and without, Gzip/ Wsa Header/ Attachment/ MTOM still for a simple SOAP Request without any file attachment I am having :

**The WS Security Header in the message is invalid. Please review the transmission instructions outlined in Section 5 of the AIR Submission Composition and Reference Guide located at https://www.irs.gov/for-Tax-Pros/Software-Developers/Information-Returns/Affordable-Care-Act-Information-Return-AIR-Program, correct any issues, and try again.**

Error Code: TPE 1122.

I have attached the complete SOAP Ui Request Message.

Any sort of Help is appreciated.

--->

```
enter code here



 POST https://la.www4.irs.gov/airp/aca/a2a/1095BC_Transmission_AATS2016 HTTP/1.1
    Content-Encoding: gzip
    Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
    Content-Type: multipart/related; type="application/xop+xml"; start="<rootpart@soapui.org>"; start-info="text/xml"; boundary="----=_Part_0_1488514502.1456157000203"
    SOAPAction: "BulkRequestTransmitter"
    MIME-Version: 1.0
    Transfer-Encoding: chunked
    Host: la.www4.irs.gov
    Connection: Keep-Alive
    User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)



    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:oas1="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:msg:acabusinessheader" xmlns:urn1="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:ext:aca:air:7.0" xmlns:urn2="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:common" xmlns:urn3="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:msg:acasecurityheader" xmlns:urn4="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:msg:irsacabulkrequesttransmitter" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:xd="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
       <soapenv:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
          <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">

             <ds:Signature Id="SIG-F8EA5798DFE03264EF145615675816614" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <ds:SignedInfo>
                   <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                      <ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="oas1 soapenv urn urn1 urn2 urn3 urn4 wsu xd" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                   </ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
                   <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
                   <ds:Reference URI="#id-E9877CA7A36541AA6A1455820267635274">
                      <ds:Transforms>
                         <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                            <ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="oas1 soapenv urn1 urn2 urn3 urn4 xd" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                         </ds:Transform>
                      </ds:Transforms>
                      <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                      <ds:DigestValue>REDACTED</ds:DigestValue>
                   </ds:Reference>
                   <ds:Reference URI="#id-E9877CA7A36541AA6A1455820267635275">
                      <ds:Transforms>
                         <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                            <ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="oas1 soapenv urn urn2 urn3 urn4 xd" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                         </ds:Transform>
                      </ds:Transforms>
                      <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                      <ds:DigestValue>REDACTED</ds:DigestValue>
                   </ds:Reference>
                   <ds:Reference URI="#id-E9877CA7A36541AA6A1455820267635276">
                      <ds:Transforms>
                         <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                            <ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="oas1 soapenv urn urn1 urn2 urn3 urn4 xd" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                         </ds:Transform>
                      </ds:Transforms>
                      <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                      <ds:DigestValue>REDACTED</ds:DigestValue>
                   </ds:Reference>
                </ds:SignedInfo>
                <ds:SignatureValue>REDACTED</ds:SignatureValue>
                <ds:KeyInfo Id="RE-Dacted">
                   <wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsu:Id="STR-abcdefghijklmnopqredacted">
                      <wsse:KeyIdentifier EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3">REDACTED</wsse:KeyIdentifier>
                   </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                </ds:KeyInfo>
             </ds:Signature>
          </wsse:Security>
          <urn3:ACASecurityHeader/>
          <urn:ACABusinessHeader wsu:Id="id-E9877CA7A36541AA6A1455820267635274">
             <urn1:UniqueTransmissionId>abcd-efgh:1234</urn1:UniqueTransmissionId>
             <urn2:Timestamp>2016-02-17T15:17:47Z</urn2:Timestamp>
          </urn:ACABusinessHeader>
          <urn1:ACATransmitterManifestReqDtl wsu:Id="id-E9877CA7A36541AA6A1455820267635275">
             <urn1:PriorYearDataInd>0</urn1:PriorYearDataInd>
             <urn2:EIN>12-34567</urn2:EIN>
             <urn1:TestFileCd>T</urn1:TestFileCd>
             <urn1:TransmitterNameGrp>
                <urn1:BusinessNameLine1Txt>SOME VALUE</urn1:BusinessNameLine1Txt>
             </urn1:TransmitterNameGrp>
             <urn1:CompanyInformationGrp>
                <urn1:MailingAddressGrp>
                   <urn1:USAddressGrp>
                      <urn1:AddressLine1Txt>SOME ADRESS</urn1:AddressLine1Txt>
                      <urn2:CityNm>SOME CITY</urn2:CityNm>
                      <urn1:USStateCd>AB</urn1:USStateCd>
                      <urn2:USZIPCd>12345</urn2:USZIPCd>
                      <urn2:USZIPExtensionCd>6789</urn2:USZIPExtensionCd>
                   </urn1:USAddressGrp>
                </urn1:MailingAddressGrp>
                <urn1:ContactNameGrp>
                   <urn2:PersonFirstNm>First</urn2:PersonFirstNm>
                   <urn2:PersonLastNm>Last</urn2:PersonLastNm>
                </urn1:ContactNameGrp>
                <urn1:ContactPhoneNum>123-456-7890</urn1:ContactPhoneNum>
             </urn1:CompanyInformationGrp>
             <urn1:VendorInformationGrp>
                <urn1:VendorCd>Some Vendor</urn1:VendorCd>
                <urn1:ContactNameGrp>
                   <urn2:PersonFirstNm>First</urn2:PersonFirstNm>
                   <urn2:PersonLastNm>Last</urn2:PersonLastNm>
                </urn1:ContactNameGrp>
                <urn1:ContactPhoneNum>Phone</urn1:ContactPhoneNum>
             </urn1:VendorInformationGrp>
             <urn1:TotalPayeeRecordCnt>1</urn1:TotalPayeeRecordCnt>
             <urn1:TotalPayerRecordCnt>1</urn1:TotalPayerRecordCnt>
             <urn1:SoftwareId>A12345678</urn1:SoftwareId>
             <urn1:FormTypeCd>1094-1095B</urn1:FormTypeCd>
             <urn2:BinaryFormatCd>application/xml</urn2:BinaryFormatCd>
             <urn2:ChecksumAugmentationNum>garbage-value</urn2:ChecksumAugmentationNum>
             <urn2:AttachmentByteSizeNum>1234</urn2:AttachmentByteSizeNum>
             <urn1:DocumentSystemFileNm>some</urn1:DocumentSystemFileNm>
          </urn1:ACATransmitterManifestReqDtl>
          <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="id-E9877CA7A36541AA6A1455820267635276">
             <wsu:Created>2016-02-17T15:41:09.678Z</wsu:Created>
             <wsu:Expires>2016-02-20T10:21:09.678Z</wsu:Expires>
          </wsu:Timestamp>
          <wsa:Action>BulkRequestTransmitter</wsa:Action>
       </soapenv:Header>
       <soapenv:Body>
          <urn4:ACABulkRequestTransmitter>
             <urn2:BulkExchangeFile>
             </urn2:BulkExchangeFile>
          </urn4:ACABulkRequestTransmitter>
       </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see the wsu:Timestamp is outside the wsse:Security, I have attached outgoing WS-Security configuration of my working SOAP UI, cross check with yours.

After applying the outgoing headers, submit the request as is and do not format the request!

[My outgoing WS-Security configuration of SOAP UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzfOp.jpg)

[My outgoing WS-Security configuration of SOAP UI-TimeStamp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PG0rN.jpg)

Comment: I configured similar settings as you did. Then when i right click on request and try to a apply outbound header it is not signing the elements at all. Can you give me more steps on how did you got past this error?

Comment: What's the value set in Time to Live property of TimeStamp? Refer to my TimeStamp screenshot attached.

Comment: Time to live: 7987987  Set precision to ms: Check

I have exact same settings that you have given.

Comment: 1. I have 3 Cert files: Root.pem, private key, subCA1.pem. Which ones you used to create Keystore to use in soapui?
2. Can you send me a sample payload which you are using in SOAP UI including http header properties?

Comment: @SouravGanguli I've attached my keystore file screenshot and the payload from SOAP UI.

Comment: Not working. Wouldn't it work if i dont send any MTOM attachement? i.e if I keep the BulkExchangeFile empty.

 Also If you have any Step By Step Documentation, please share with me in souravganguli23@gmail.com

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello Jags,

Your Solution worked, i think I got past TPE1122 error, now there is some problem with MTOM encoded XML file with a simple XML attachment. The Error code is TPE1114. Please throw some light on this at the earliest.

Comment: @SouravGanguli. how are you creating the MTOM atachment? Can you share the Attachment tab screenshot of SOAP UI?

Comment: Hello jags,

I have a XML file which i need to attach after encoding it and passing the digest value in one of the element in request payload.

Steps:
1. Base 64 Encoded the XML 1094B form thorugh freeformatter then passing the digest value in the BulkExchangeFile element in request payload.(provided earlier)

Answer (score 0):

SOAP UI KeyStore using pfx file.
[SOAP UI KeyStore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xnqU.jpg)

Request payload:

```
POST https://la.www4.irs.gov/airp/aca/a2a/1095BC_Transmission_AATS2016 HTTP/1.1
SOAPAction: BulkRequestTransmitter
Content-Type: multipart/related; type="application/xop+xml"; start="<rootpart@soapui.org>
  "; start-info="text/xml"; boundary="----=_Part_26_1277305220.1456248891536"
  Host: la.www4.irs.gov
  Content-Length: 17728
  Expect: 100-continue
  Connection: Keep-Alive

  ------=_Part_26_1277305220.1456248891536
  Content-Type: application/xop+xml; charset=UTF-8; type="text/xml"
  Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
  Content-ID: <rootpart@soapui.org>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
    <wsse:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
      <ds:Signature Id="SIG-3ED4996B507C9FE4891456248845324120" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <ds:SignedInfo>
          <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#WithComments"/>
          <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
          <ds:Reference URI="#TS-3ED4996B507C9FE4891456248845320116">
            <ds:Transforms>
              <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                <InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="wsse s" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
              </ds:Transform>
            </ds:Transforms>
            <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
            <ds:DigestValue>....</ds:DigestValue>
          </ds:Reference>
          <ds:Reference URI="#id-D4CA0E52B9727D4C0A14551257302705">
            <ds:Transforms>
              <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                <InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="s" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
              </ds:Transform>
            </ds:Transforms>
            <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
            <ds:DigestValue>....</ds:DigestValue>
          </ds:Reference>
          <ds:Reference URI="#id-1781945826">
            <ds:Transforms>
              <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                <InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="s" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
              </ds:Transform>
            </ds:Transforms>
            <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
            <ds:DigestValue>.....</ds:DigestValue>
          </ds:Reference>
        </ds:SignedInfo>
        <ds:SignatureValue>.....</ds:SignatureValue>
        <ds:KeyInfo Id="KI-3ED4996B507C9FE4891456248845324118">
          <wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsu:Id="STR-3ED4996B507C9FE4891456248845324119">
            <wsse:KeyIdentifier EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3">....</wsse:KeyIdentifier>
          </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
        </ds:KeyInfo>
      </ds:Signature>
      <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-3ED4996B507C9FE4891456248845320116">
        <wsu:Created>2016-02-23T17:34:05.320Z</wsu:Created>
        <wsu:Expires>2016-05-26T04:27:12.320Z</wsu:Expires>
      </wsu:Timestamp>
    </wsse:Security>
    <ns0:ACABusinessHeader ns1:Id="id-1781945826" ns2:anyAttr="anyAttrContents" xmlns:ns0="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:msg:acabusinessheader" xmlns:ns1="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:ns2="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:msg:acabusinessheaderanyAttr">
      <ns3:UniqueTransmissionId xmlns:ns3="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:ext:aca:air:7.0">5a79b747-f622-4fe0-b5a7-4ab52226bc70:SYS12:xxxxx::T</ns3:UniqueTransmissionId>
      <ns4:Timestamp xmlns:ns4="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:common">2016-02-09T12:34:33Z</ns4:Timestamp>
    </ns0:ACABusinessHeader>
    <ACATransmitterManifestReqDtl d1p1:Id="id-D4CA0E52B9727D4C0A14551257302705" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:msg:form1094-1095BCtransmitterreqmessage IRS-Form1094-1095BCTransmitterReqMessage.xsd" xmlns="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:ext:aca:air:7.0" xmlns:d1p1="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:irs="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:common" xmlns:n1="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:msg:form1094-1095BCtransmitterreqmessage" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">         
    </ACATransmitterManifestReqDtl>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <ns0:ACABulkRequestTransmitter version="1.0" xmlns:ns0="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:msg:irsacabulkrequesttransmitter">
      <ns1:BulkExchangeFile xmlns:ns1="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:common">
        <inc:Include href="cid:1094B_Request_xxxxx_20160211T170145000Z.xml" xmlns:inc="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include"/>
      </ns1:BulkExchangeFile>
    </ns0:ACABulkRequestTransmitter>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
------=_Part_26_1277305220.1456248891536
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=Cp1252;
name=1094B_Request_xxxxx_20160211T170145000Z.xml
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-ID: <1094B_Request_xxxxx_20160211T170145000Z.xml>
Content-Disposition: attachment;name="1094B_Request_xxxxx_20160211T170145000Z.xml"; 

filename="1094B_Request_xxxxx_20160211T170145000Z.xml"
< 1094 Bulk file removed>
          ------=_Part_26_1277305220.1456248891536--
```

Comment: They are accepting that? It is missing the MIME-Version header. Thought that was required.

Comment: And your Content-Transfer-Encoding isn't 7bit as their documentation also says is required. I'd be really surprised they accept this considering how plainly they say it is required in the docs!

Comment: Hey @Bon, yes it is working, I've tried all these combinations.All they care is that content-type is application/xml or text/xml for attachment part

Comment: Crazy! There is such an odd combination of lax and strict requirements peppered throughout this entire process... Thanks very much for letting me know.

Comment: no problem! btw, how are you signing the messages? were you able to succeed and get past TPE1122 error thru your application?

Comment: I am signing using the SignedXml class to generate the Signature element. I'm manually constructing my Xml and sending it over HTTP myself instead of using WCF or the older web services client since those won't work with MTOM and signing since signing always happens last in the pipeline, but won't work since MTOM breaks the outbound message's Xml.

Comment: @Bon, I'm also signing the message using SignedXml class but the digests are not matching for Business header and Manifest Request detail elements, any thoughts?

Comment: What error are you getting in your response from them precisely? Because there should also be a digest for the Security element's Timestamp element additionally. I had to tweak the Signature element to fix the KeyInfo element using LINQ to Xml since there isn't a way for .Net to generate a BinarySecurityToken as an inline KeyIdentifier as far as tell. So I do var signature  =XElement.Load(signedXml.GetXml().CreateNavigator().ReadSubtree()); and then do signature.LastNode.Remove(); and var token=Convert.ToBase64String(new X509SecurityToken(cert).RawData);  to create the KeyInfo element manually

Comment: I get TPE1122 and while debugging on the call with IRS, They are saying that timestamp digest is matching but not the business header and manifest request detail, they even sent me the expected digest values. I  hard coded the Key Info section as below. were you able to get Receipt ID with your approach?

Comment: KeyInfoNode keyInfoNode = new KeyInfoNode();  XmlElement securityRef = xmlDoc.CreateElement("wsse", "SecurityTokenReference", wsseNs);securityRef.SetAttribute("Id", wsuNs, "STR-B33599504712DEFDDE1455729620600114");XmlElement keyIdentifier = xmlDoc.CreateElement("wsse:KeyIdentifier", wsseNs);
keyIdentifier.InnerText = Convert.ToBase64String(cert.RawData);XmlAttribute valueType = xmlDoc.CreateAttribute("ValueType");valueType.Value = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3";keyIdentifier.Attributes.Append(valueType);

Comment: XmlAttribute encodingType = xmlDoc.CreateAttribute("EncodingType");encodingType.Value = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary";keyIdentifier.Attributes.Append(encodingType);securityRef.AppendChild(keyIdentifier);keyInfoNode.Value = securityRef;KeyInfo keyInfo = new KeyInfo();keyInfo.Id = "KI-3";keyInfo.AddClause(keyInfoNode);

Comment: My ws-security is passing but I'm getting rejected because they claim my submission isn't MTOM encoded, despite my literally approaching 100 times I've checked it over with the w3c specs and other peoples' samples. So I am not totally sure what to expect at this point. Was AATS down for you today too, by the way?

Comment: Seems like its down today as well,they said its because of maintenance build over the weekend.

Comment: Yes IRS is down, I am stuck with the Attachment file.

Comment: I just got it all working fully! My problem was that my HTTP header for Content-Type was soap+xml instead of xop+xml! I can now confirm for you that signing in the manner I described does work :D

Comment: @Bon , Can you share some code snippets for signing message! it will help me a lot!

Comment: @Bon, we are calculating digests of outer xml of wsu:Timestamp, urn:ACATransmitterManifestReqDtl and urn2:ACABusinessHeader. Then adding them to SignedInfo having Reference elements as per chapter 5 of A2A doc. Then Digest of SignedInfo's outerXML is computed and signed to generate SignatureValue. The certficate is enclosed in <ds:KeyInfo><wsse:SecurityTokenReference .><wsse:KeyIdentifier EncodingType=...#Base64Binary" ValueType="...#X509v3">CertValue</wsse:KeyIdentifier></wsse:SecurityTokenReference></ds:KeyInfo>. We have WS-Sec header error. R u also encrypting these three elements?

Comment: I am indeed, but I'm relying on the SignedXml class to handle it all for me by passing to it the Id attributes to those 3 elements to be signed. All I have to do is modify the resulting KeyInfo element to match their KeyIdentifier structure.

Comment: Thanks Bob. We have tried your thing too both in Java and .NET but still getting ws security error. When tried to reach IRS team over phone, they said refer the document. We have done thoroughly everything mentioned in document and cross checked again, again and again but not sure what's going wrong. Could you pls share required part of your code to pass this and any other reference if you have which help us and few others to who are blocked into it? and Is there any specific data needs to be posted for AATS testing? Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: @Bon, we are able to pass ws security now. Getting MTOM attachment error now. Any clue on this?

Comment: Make sure your HTTP header content type is set to Multipart/Related and the type inside that string is "application/xop+xml" along with all the other MIME boundary metadata.

Comment: Tried with this but no luck. Can u pls share your settings screen shot?

Comment: @Bon, Able to solve WS Security in java and SOAP UI but in .NET no luck yet. Our application is in .NET and we are looking for a solution in .NET. Do you have any reference where .NET code works for this?